# How to add a value in regedit key while creating Visual studio Setup Project (.msi)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, setup-project, regedit

I know the question is a bit confusing so allow me to elaborate everything from the start to the end.

1. I am creating a **setup project** in visual studio.
2. I have created a **Regidit key** and with a **string value**

> {"Dys":[],"Frequency":"15","Hour":11,"Minutes":2,"ScheduledDate":"/Date(1440095400000+0530)/","ScheduledOn":null,"scheduleType":4}

[image]
3. while building the project I am getting an error (given below)

> Error 1   Invalid characters '{"Dys":[],"Frequency":"15","Hour":11,"Minutes":2,"ScheduledDate":"/Date(1440095400000+0530)/","ScheduledOn":null,"scheduleType":4}' in value for registry value 'ScheduleScan', located in 'HKLM\Software\TechHeal\TechHeal'  C:\Users\Paxcel\Desktop\svn\Code\TechHeal\TechHeal 15 June - New Design\Setup Projects (MSI)\Techheal\Techheal\Techheal.vdproj  Techheal

However, If I am directly creating the (regedit)string key from the Regedit viewer of windows then its creating the key with the same value without any issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you create registry settings through windows installer, Non-ASCII characters cannot be evaluated by the windows installer and you might get similar error message.

But I don't see any non-ASCII in the value that you have used.

Try removing the square brackets. If that works you can use `()`

> {"Dys":**[]**,"Frequency":"15","Hour":11,"Minutes":2,"ScheduledDate":"/Date(1440095400000+0530)/","ScheduledOn":null,"scheduleType":4}

Comment: '{' and '[' are causing this error. Actually I want to store JSON in regedit.

Comment: When you save the string in registry you can use () instead of [] and before processing this JSON you could replace them again with [].